# Replace text in header script not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script using Google Apps Script to allow data from Google Sheets (via Google Form input) to populate a Google Document. It works fine except it will not work to replace text in the header. Replacing text in the body works just fine and the document populates just fine without errors. I am looking to put the same exact text in each header so it should not be complicated. I use this same script for multiple Google Sheets and Forms with 100% success but some (like this one) just do not work to replace the header text only. I also double checked my Google Doc which correctly has {{QC}} and {{QD}} in the header section.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
function autofillForm(e) {
    var timestamp = e.values[0];
    var timeslot = e.values[1];
    var QC = e.values[2];
    var QD = e.values[3];
    var QE = e.values[4];
    var QF = e.values[5];
    var QG = e.values[6];
    var QH = e.values[7];
    var QI = e.values[8];
    var QJ = e.values[9];
    var QK = e.values[10];
    var QL = e.values[11];
    var QM = e.values[12];
    var QN = e.values[13];
    var QO = e.values[14];
    var QP = e.values[15];
    var QQ = e.values[16];
    var QR = e.values[17];
    var QS = e.values[18];
    var QT = e.values[19];
    var QU = e.values[20];
    var QV = e.values[21];
    var QW = e.values[22];
    var QX = e.values[23];
    var QY = e.values[24];
    var QZ = e.values[25];
    var QAA = e.values[26];
    var QAB = e.values[27];
    var QAC = e.values[28];
    var QAD = e.values[29];
    var QAE = e.values[30];
    var QAF = e.values[31];
    var QAG = e.values[32];
    var QAH = e.values[33];
    var QAI = e.values[34];
    var QAJ = e.values[35];
    var QAK = e.values[36];
    var QAL = e.values[37];
    var QAM = e.values[38];
    var QAN = e.values[39];
    var QAO = e.values[40];
    var QAP = e.values[41];
    var QAQ = e.values[42];
    var QAR = e.values[43];
    var QAS = e.values[44];
    var QAT = e.values[45];
    var QAU = e.values[46];
    var QAV = e.values[47];
    var QAW = e.values[48];
    var QAX = e.values[49];
    var QAY = e.values[50];
    var QAZ = e.values[51];
    var QBA = e.values[52];
    var QBB = e.values[53];
    var QBC = e.values[54];
    var QBD = e.values[55];
    var QBE = e.values[56];
    var QBF = e.values[57];
    var QBG = e.values[58];
    var QBH = e.values[59];
    var QBI = e.values[60];
    var QBJ = e.values[61];
    var QBK = e.values[62];
    var QBL = e.values[63];
    var QBM = e.values[64];
    var QBN = e.values[65];
    var QBO = e.values[66];
    var QBP = e.values[67];
    var QBQ = e.values[68];
    var QBR = e.values[69];
    var QBS = e.values[70];
    var QBT = e.values[71];
    var QBU = e.values[72];
    var QBV = e.values[73];
    var QBW = e.values[74];
    var QBX = e.values[75];
    var QBY = e.values[76];
    var QBZ = e.values[77];
    var QCA = e.values[78];
    var QCB = e.values[79];
    var QCC = e.values[80];
    var QCD = e.values[81];
    var QCE = e.values[82];
    var QCF = e.values[83];
    var QCG = e.values[84];
    var QCH = e.values[85];
    var QCI = e.values[86];
    var QCJ = e.values[87];
    var QCK = e.values[88];
    var QCL = e.values[89];
    var QCM = e.values[90];
    var QCN = e.values[91];
    var QCO = e.values[92];
    var QCP = e.values[93];
    var QCQ = e.values[94];
    var QCR = e.values[95];
    var QCS = e.values[96];
    var QCT = e.values[97];
    var QCU = e.values[98];
    var QCV = e.values[99];
    var QCW = e.values[100];
    var QCX = e.values[101];
    var QCY = e.values[102];
    var QCZ = e.values[103];
    var QDA = e.values[104];
    var QDB = e.values[105];
    var QDC = e.values[106];
    var QDD = e.values[107];
    var QDE = e.values[108];
    var QDF = e.values[119];
    var QDG = e.values[110];
    var QDH = e.values[111];
    var QDI = e.values[112];
    var QDJ = e.values[113];
    var QDK = e.values[114];
    var QDL = e.values[115];
    var QDM = e.values[116];
    var QDN = e.values[117];
    var QDO = e.values[118];
    var QDP = e.values[119];
    var QDQ = e.values[120];
    var QDR = e.values[121];
    var QDS = e.values[122];
    var QDT = e.values[123];
    var QDU = e.values[124];
    var QDV = e.values[125];
    var QDW = e.values[126];
    var QDX = e.values[127];
    var QDY = e.values[128];
    var QDZ = e.values[129];
    var QEA = e.values[130];
    var QEB = e.values[131];
    var QEC = e.values[132];
    var QED = e.values[133];
    var QEE = e.values[134];
    var QEF = e.values[135];
    var QEG = e.values[136];
    var QEH = e.values[137];
    var QEI = e.values[138];
    var QEJ = e.values[139];
    var QEK = e.values[140];
    var QEL = e.values[141];
    var QEM = e.values[142];
    var QEN = e.values[143];
    var QEO = e.values[144]; 
    var QEP = e.values[145];
    var QEQ = e.values[146];
    var QER = e.values[147];
    var QES = e.values[148];
    var QET = e.values[149];
    var QEU = e.values[150];
    var QEV = e.values[151];
    var QEW = e.values[152];
    var QEX = e.values[153];
    var QEY = e.values[154];
    var QEZ = e.values[155];
    var QFA = e.values[156];
    var QFB = e.values[157];
    var QFC = e.values[158];
    var QFD = e.values[159];
    var QFE = e.values[160];
    var QFF = e.values[161];
    var QFG = e.values[162];
    var QFH = e.values[163];
    var QFI = e.values[164];
    var QFJ = e.values[165];
    var QFK = e.values[166];
    var QFL = e.values[167];
    var QFM = e.values[168];
    var QFN = e.values[169];
    var QFO = e.values[170]; 
    var QFP = e.values[171];
    var QFQ = e.values[172];
    var QFR = e.values[173];
    var QFS = e.values[174];
    var QFT = e.values[175];
    var QFU = e.values[176];
    var QFV = e.values[177];
    var QFW = e.values[178];
    var QFX = e.values[179];
    var QFY = e.values[180];
    var QFZ = e.values[181];
    var QGA = e.values[182];
    var QGB = e.values[183];
    var QGC = e.values[184];
    var QGD = e.values[185];
    var QGE = e.values[186];
    var QGF = e.values[187];
    var QGG = e.values[188];
    var QGH = e.values[189];
    var QGI = e.values[190];
    var QGJ = e.values[191];
    var QGK = e.values[192];
    var QGL = e.values[193];
    var QGM = e.values[194];
    var QGN = e.values[195];
    var QGO = e.values[196]; 
    var QGP = e.values[197];
    var QGQ = e.values[198];
    var QGR = e.values[199];
    var QGS = e.values[200];
    var QGT = e.values[201];
    var QGU = e.values[202];
    var QGV = e.values[203];
    var QGW = e.values[204];
    var QGX = e.values[205];
    var QGY = e.values[206];
    var QGZ = e.values[207];
    var QHA = e.values[208];
    var QHB = e.values[209];
    var QHC = e.values[210];
    var QHD = e.values[211];
    var QHE = e.values[212];
    var QHF = e.values[213];
    var QHG = e.values[214];
    var QHH = e.values[215];
    var QHI = e.values[216];
    var QHJ = e.values[217];
    var QHK = e.values[218];
    var QHL = e.values[219];
    var QHM = e.values[220];
    var QHN = e.values[221];
    var QHO = e.values[222]; 
    var QHP = e.values[223];
    var QHQ = e.values[224];
    var QHR = e.values[225];
    var QHS = e.values[226];
    var QHT = e.values[227];
    var QHU = e.values[228];
    var QHV = e.values[229];
    var QHW = e.values[230];
    var QHX = e.values[231];
    var QHY = e.values[232];
    var QHZ = e.values[233];
    var QIA = e.values[234];
    var QIB = e.values[235];
    var QIC = e.values[236];
    var QID = e.values[237];
    var QIE = e.values[238];
    var QIF = e.values[239];
    var QIG = e.values[240];
    var QIH = e.values[241];
    var QII = e.values[242];
    var QIJ = e.values[243];
    var QIK = e.values[244];
    var QIL = e.values[245];
    var QIM = e.values[246];
    var QIN = e.values[247];
    var QIO = e.values[248]; 
    var QIP = e.values[249];
    var QIQ = e.values[250];
    var QIR = e.values[251];
    var QIS = e.values[252];
    var QIT = e.values[253];
    var QIU = e.values[254];
    var QIV = e.values[255];
    var QIW = e.values[256];
    var QIX = e.values[257];
    var QIY = e.values[258];
    var QIZ = e.values[259];
    var QJA = e.values[260];
    var QJB = e.values[261];
    var QJC = e.values[262];
    var QJD = e.values[263];
    var QJE = e.values[264];
    var QJF = e.values[265];
    var QJG = e.values[266];
    var QJH = e.values[267];
    var QJI = e.values[268];
    var QJJ = e.values[269];
    var QJK = e.values[270];
    var QJL = e.values[271];
    var QJM = e.values[272];
    var QJN = e.values[273];
    var QJO = e.values[274];
    var QJP = e.values[275];

    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("XXX");
    var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXX");

    var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(QF + QG + timeslot + QJP, templateResponseFolder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var header = doc.getHeader();

    header.replaceText("{{QC}}", QC);
    header.replaceText("{{QD}}", QD);
    body.replaceText("{{QE}}", QE);
    body.replaceText("{{QF}}", QF);
    body.replaceText("{{QG}}", QG);
    body.replaceText("{{QH}}", QH);
    body.replaceText("{{QI}}", QI);
    body.replaceText("{{QJ}}", QJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QK}}", QK);
    body.replaceText("{{QL}}", QL);
    body.replaceText("{{QM}}", QM);
    body.replaceText("{{QN}}", QN);
    body.replaceText("{{QO}}", QO);
    body.replaceText("{{QP}}", QP);
    body.replaceText("{{QQ}}", QQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QR}}", QR);
    body.replaceText("{{QS}}", QS);
    body.replaceText("{{QT}}", QT);
    body.replaceText("{{QU}}", QU);
    body.replaceText("{{QV}}", QV);
    body.replaceText("{{QW}}", QW);
    body.replaceText("{{QX}}", QX);
    body.replaceText("{{QY}}", QY);
    body.replaceText("{{QZ}}", QZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QAA}}", QAA);
    body.replaceText("{{QAB}}", QAB);
    body.replaceText("{{QAC}}", QAC);
    body.replaceText("{{QAD}}", QAD);
    body.replaceText("{{QAE}}", QAE);
    body.replaceText("{{QAF}}", QAF);
    body.replaceText("{{QAG}}", QAG);
    body.replaceText("{{QAH}}", QAH);
    body.replaceText("{{QAI}}", QAI);
    body.replaceText("{{QAJ}}", QAJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QAK}}", QAK);
    body.replaceText("{{QAL}}", QAL);
    body.replaceText("{{QAM}}", QAM);
    body.replaceText("{{QAN}}", QAN);
    body.replaceText("{{QAO}}", QAO);
    body.replaceText("{{QAP}}", QAP);
    body.replaceText("{{QAQ}}", QAQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QAR}}", QAR);
    body.replaceText("{{QAS}}", QAS);
    body.replaceText("{{QAT}}", QAT);
    body.replaceText("{{QAU}}", QAU);
    body.replaceText("{{QAV}}", QAV);
    body.replaceText("{{QAW}}", QAW);
    body.replaceText("{{QAX}}", QAX);
    body.replaceText("{{QAY}}", QAY);
    body.replaceText("{{QAZ}}", QAZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QBA}}", QBA);
    body.replaceText("{{QBB}}", QBB);
    body.replaceText("{{QBC}}", QBC);
    body.replaceText("{{QBD}}", QBD);
    body.replaceText("{{QBE}}", QBE);
    body.replaceText("{{QBF}}", QBF);
    body.replaceText("{{QBG}}", QBG);
    body.replaceText("{{QBH}}", QBH);
    body.replaceText("{{QBI}}", QBI);
    body.replaceText("{{QBJ}}", QBJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QBK}}", QBK);
    body.replaceText("{{QBL}}", QBL);
    body.replaceText("{{QBM}}", QBM);
    body.replaceText("{{QBN}}", QBN);
    body.replaceText("{{QBO}}", QBO);
    body.replaceText("{{QBP}}", QBP);
    body.replaceText("{{QBQ}}", QBQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QBR}}", QBR);
    body.replaceText("{{QBS}}", QBS);
    body.replaceText("{{QBT}}", QBT);
    body.replaceText("{{QBU}}", QBU);
    body.replaceText("{{QBV}}", QBV);
    body.replaceText("{{QBW}}", QBW);
    body.replaceText("{{QBX}}", QBX);
    body.replaceText("{{QBY}}", QBY);
    body.replaceText("{{QBZ}}", QBZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QCA}}", QCA);
    body.replaceText("{{QCB}}", QCB);
    body.replaceText("{{QCC}}", QCC);
    body.replaceText("{{QCD}}", QCD);
    body.replaceText("{{QCE}}", QCE);
    body.replaceText("{{QCF}}", QCF);
    body.replaceText("{{QCG}}", QCG);
    body.replaceText("{{QCH}}", QCH);
    body.replaceText("{{QCI}}", QCI);
    body.replaceText("{{QCJ}}", QCJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QCK}}", QCK);
    body.replaceText("{{QCL}}", QCL);
    body.replaceText("{{QCM}}", QCM);
    body.replaceText("{{QCN}}", QCN);
    body.replaceText("{{QCO}}", QCO);
    body.replaceText("{{QCP}}", QCP);
    body.replaceText("{{QCQ}}", QCQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QCQ}}", QCQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QCR}}", QCR);
    body.replaceText("{{QCS}}", QCS);
    body.replaceText("{{QCT}}", QCT);
    body.replaceText("{{QCU}}", QCU);
    body.replaceText("{{QCV}}", QCV);
    body.replaceText("{{QCW}}", QCW);
    body.replaceText("{{QCX}}", QCX);
    body.replaceText("{{QCY}}", QCY);
    body.replaceText("{{QCZ}}", QCZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QDA}}", QDA);
    body.replaceText("{{QDB}}", QDB);
    body.replaceText("{{QDC}}", QDC);
    body.replaceText("{{QDD}}", QDD);
    body.replaceText("{{QDE}}", QDE);
    body.replaceText("{{QDF}}", QDF);
    body.replaceText("{{QDG}}", QDG);
    body.replaceText("{{QDH}}", QDH);
    body.replaceText("{{QDI}}", QDI);
    body.replaceText("{{QDJ}}", QDJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QDK}}", QDK);
    body.replaceText("{{QDL}}", QDL);
    body.replaceText("{{QDM}}", QDM);
    body.replaceText("{{QDN}}", QDN);
    body.replaceText("{{QDO}}", QDO);
    body.replaceText("{{QDP}}", QDP);
    body.replaceText("{{QDQ}}", QDQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QDR}}", QDR);
    body.replaceText("{{QDS}}", QDS);
    body.replaceText("{{QDT}}", QDT);
    body.replaceText("{{QDU}}", QDU);
    body.replaceText("{{QDV}}", QDV);
    body.replaceText("{{QDW}}", QDW);
    body.replaceText("{{QDX}}", QDX);
    body.replaceText("{{QDY}}", QDY);
    body.replaceText("{{QDZ}}", QDZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QEA}}", QEA);
    body.replaceText("{{QEB}}", QEB);
    body.replaceText("{{QEC}}", QEC);
    body.replaceText("{{QED}}", QED);
    body.replaceText("{{QEE}}", QEE);
    body.replaceText("{{QEF}}", QEF);
    body.replaceText("{{QEG}}", QEG);
    body.replaceText("{{QEH}}", QEH);
    body.replaceText("{{QEI}}", QEI);
    body.replaceText("{{QEJ}}", QEJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QEK}}", QEK);
    body.replaceText("{{QEL}}", QEL);
    body.replaceText("{{QEM}}", QEM);
    body.replaceText("{{QEN}}", QEN);
    body.replaceText("{{QEO}}", QEO);
    body.replaceText("{{QEP}}", QEP);
    body.replaceText("{{QEQ}}", QEQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QER}}", QER);
    body.replaceText("{{QES}}", QES);
    body.replaceText("{{QET}}", QET);
    body.replaceText("{{QEU}}", QEU);
    body.replaceText("{{QEV}}", QEV);
    body.replaceText("{{QEW}}", QEW);
    body.replaceText("{{QEX}}", QEX);
    body.replaceText("{{QEY}}", QEY);
    body.replaceText("{{QEZ}}", QEZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QFA}}", QFA);
    body.replaceText("{{QFB}}", QFB);
    body.replaceText("{{QFC}}", QFC);
    body.replaceText("{{QFD}}", QFD);
    body.replaceText("{{QFE}}", QFE);
    body.replaceText("{{QFF}}", QFF);
    body.replaceText("{{QFG}}", QFG);
    body.replaceText("{{QFH}}", QFH);
    body.replaceText("{{QFI}}", QFI);
    body.replaceText("{{QFJ}}", QFJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QFK}}", QFK);
    body.replaceText("{{QFL}}", QFL);
    body.replaceText("{{QFM}}", QFM);
    body.replaceText("{{QFN}}", QFN);
    body.replaceText("{{QFO}}", QFO);
    body.replaceText("{{QFP}}", QFP);
    body.replaceText("{{QFQ}}", QFQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QFR}}", QFR);
    body.replaceText("{{QFS}}", QFS);
    body.replaceText("{{QFT}}", QFT);
    body.replaceText("{{QFU}}", QFU);
    body.replaceText("{{QFV}}", QFV);
    body.replaceText("{{QFW}}", QFW);
    body.replaceText("{{QFX}}", QFX);
    body.replaceText("{{QFY}}", QFY);
    body.replaceText("{{QFZ}}", QFZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QGA}}", QGA);
    body.replaceText("{{QGB}}", QGB);
    body.replaceText("{{QGC}}", QGC);
    body.replaceText("{{QGD}}", QGD);
    body.replaceText("{{QGE}}", QGE);
    body.replaceText("{{QGF}}", QGF);
    body.replaceText("{{QGG}}", QGG);
    body.replaceText("{{QGH}}", QGH);
    body.replaceText("{{QGI}}", QGI);
    body.replaceText("{{QGJ}}", QGJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QGK}}", QGK);
    body.replaceText("{{QGL}}", QGL);
    body.replaceText("{{QGM}}", QGM);
    body.replaceText("{{QGN}}", QGN);
    body.replaceText("{{QGO}}", QGO);
    body.replaceText("{{QGP}}", QGP);
    body.replaceText("{{QGQ}}", QGQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QGR}}", QGR);
    body.replaceText("{{QGS}}", QGS);
    body.replaceText("{{QGT}}", QGT);
    body.replaceText("{{QGU}}", QGU);
    body.replaceText("{{QGV}}", QGV);
    body.replaceText("{{QGW}}", QGW);
    body.replaceText("{{QGX}}", QGX);
    body.replaceText("{{QGY}}", QGY);
    body.replaceText("{{QGZ}}", QGZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QHA}}", QHA);
    body.replaceText("{{QHB}}", QHB);
    body.replaceText("{{QHC}}", QHC);
    body.replaceText("{{QHD}}", QHD);
    body.replaceText("{{QHE}}", QHE);
    body.replaceText("{{QHF}}", QHF);
    body.replaceText("{{QHG}}", QHG);
    body.replaceText("{{QHH}}", QHH);
    body.replaceText("{{QHI}}", QHI);
    body.replaceText("{{QHJ}}", QHJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QHK}}", QHK);
    body.replaceText("{{QHL}}", QHL);
    body.replaceText("{{QHM}}", QHM);
    body.replaceText("{{QHN}}", QHN);
    body.replaceText("{{QHO}}", QHO);
    body.replaceText("{{QHP}}", QHP);
    body.replaceText("{{QHQ}}", QHQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QHR}}", QHR);
    body.replaceText("{{QHS}}", QHS);
    body.replaceText("{{QHT}}", QHT);
    body.replaceText("{{QHU}}", QHU);
    body.replaceText("{{QHV}}", QHV);
    body.replaceText("{{QHW}}", QHW);
    body.replaceText("{{QHX}}", QHX);
    body.replaceText("{{QHY}}", QHY);
    body.replaceText("{{QHZ}}", QHZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QIA}}", QIA);
    body.replaceText("{{QIB}}", QIB);
    body.replaceText("{{QIC}}", QIC);
    body.replaceText("{{QID}}", QID);
    body.replaceText("{{QIE}}", QIE);
    body.replaceText("{{QIF}}", QIF);
    body.replaceText("{{QIG}}", QIG);
    body.replaceText("{{QIH}}", QIH);
    body.replaceText("{{QII}}", QII);
    body.replaceText("{{QIJ}}", QIJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QIK}}", QIK);
    body.replaceText("{{QIL}}", QIL);
    body.replaceText("{{QIM}}", QIM);
    body.replaceText("{{QIN}}", QIN);
    body.replaceText("{{QIO}}", QIO);
    body.replaceText("{{QIP}}", QIP);
    body.replaceText("{{QIQ}}", QIQ);
    body.replaceText("{{QIR}}", QIR);
    body.replaceText("{{QIS}}", QIS);
    body.replaceText("{{QIT}}", QIT);
    body.replaceText("{{QIU}}", QIU);
    body.replaceText("{{QIV}}", QIV);
    body.replaceText("{{QIW}}", QIW);
    body.replaceText("{{QIX}}", QIX);
    body.replaceText("{{QIY}}", QIY);
    body.replaceText("{{QIZ}}", QIZ);
    body.replaceText("{{QJA}}", QJA);
    body.replaceText("{{QJB}}", QJB);
    body.replaceText("{{QJC}}", QJC);
    body.replaceText("{{QJD}}", QJD);
    body.replaceText("{{QJE}}", QJE);
    body.replaceText("{{QJF}}", QJF);
    body.replaceText("{{QJG}}", QJG);
    body.replaceText("{{QJH}}", QJH);
    body.replaceText("{{QJI}}", QJI);
    body.replaceText("{{QJJ}}", QJJ);
    body.replaceText("{{QJK}}", QJK);
    body.replaceText("{{QJL}}", QJL);
    body.replaceText("{{QJM}}", QJM);
    body.replaceText("{{QJN}}", QJN);
    body.replaceText("{{QJO}}", QJO);
    body.replaceText("{{QJP}}", QJP);

    doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

Comment: Side note (not an answer): This may just be a copy/paste issue - but your code has one opening bracket `{` at the start, but two closing brackets `}` at the end. You can [edit] to make sure the code in the question matches the code you are using.

Comment: Do you have a sample document that replicates the problem? `header.replaceText("{{QC}}", "abc");` worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I deleted the 2nd closing bracket. Again the script works well without errors, but only the header will not replace text with what is in the Google Sheet. Very odd. I have this same code for multiple scripts and it works to replace header for about 50% of them. I cannot find a reason why it does not work for 100% of them. My actual code is very long so I edited it so you can see the entire thing.

Comment: Can you share a sample document and sheet? It may be since the code is so repetitive that there is a typo somewhere. Maybe there is a better approach, but for that it would be good to see the big picture.

Comment: I certainly could share these items but I am unsure how this would help. The issue is that everything works 100% correctly to replace the text in the body, which is where the repetitive nature lies. I am trying to replace only 2 items in the header. When my project is triggered, the code executes without errors and what I see in the header is {{QC}} and {{QD}} whereas in the body, all text is replaced with the text in the corresponding cells in the sheet. It appears that there is no issue with the code but unfortunately, Google Apps Script is not executing it correctly?

Comment: Thats the thing, it is very unlikely that Apps Script is executing it incorrectly, though it is possible, of course. I can't reproduce something like this (i've done some tests and mshcruz also did), so it may be as a result of the larger context of the project. So without being able to reproduce it, we can't diagnose it, only make guesses at what could be wrong. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions. I have deleted and started over from scratch with the same results. I will follow the minimal reproducible example suggestions and start removing code bit by bit to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Interestingly, I deleted the following code:   var header = doc.getHeader();

  header.replaceText("{{QC}}", QC);
  header.replaceText("{{QD}}", QD); and everything worked 100% fine. I then re-added this header related code as well as a line for header.replaceText ("{{QE}}", QE) - since I know this works to replace text in the body (and I added {{QE}} to the header section of my Google Doc. It still it does not work to replace any text in the header section. Do you think this is an error on the Apps Script side? I appreciate all of the assistance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, text is being replaced in the header just fine. Please consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: function autofillPhysicalForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var timeslot = e.values[1];
  var QC = e.values[2];
  var QD = e.values[3];
  var QE = e.values[4];
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("XXX");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXX");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(timeslot, templateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var header = doc.getHeader();

  header.replaceText("{{QC}}", QC);
  header.replaceText("{{QD}}", QD);
  header.replaceText("{{QE}}", QE);

  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}

Comment: @lamblichus That is the minimal reproducible example. The header still says {{QC}} {{QD}} {{QE}}. The Gdoc file is named appropriately and the program ran without errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I mentioned before, this is not reproducible. The only thing I can think of in this case is that you're looking for changes in the original file and not in the copy. But I used this latest code you provide and it updated the header of the copied file as expected. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @lamblichus. I am not sure what to do next. I deleted the Gdoc and started over. I deleted the GSheet and started over, re-wrote the code. It still does not work. If I make a new form and do the same thing, it works just fine. Could there be a glitch with the Google Form itself? It is such a long form, that deleting and starting from scratch on this would be quite onerous. I am also unable to reproduce the problem outside of using this particular Google Form. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Wait, you haven't checked whether `QC`, `QD` and `QE` get populated? If they get populated, this is a problem with the doc. If it's not, it's a problem with the form. Use [Logger.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata) on these variables and check the `Executions` tab to see whether they are populated successfully. By the way, it's `Iamblichus`, with capital `i`. If you write the name with `L` I won't get notified.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for the clarification re: name. I have checked regarding population of QC, QD, QE. If code includes body+header replaceText for QC, QD, QE, they do not populate in the header from the data in the GSheet, but they will populate appropriately in the body. Not sure how this could be happening. All executions say "No logs are available for this execution". So it sounds like it is a problem with the form. Is there any way to copy the form and not have the error persist? Like I mentioned before, it is over 100 questions and would be quite arduous to re-do the form from scratch.

Comment: `All executions say "No logs are available for this execution"` Have you tried using `Logger.log` for that? (e.g. `Logger.log(QC);`). If that's not the case, then no question you are getting `No logs are available for this execution`. Can you try doing that?

Comment: @Iamblichus. I believe the problem was with a malfunctioning or corrupted Gdoc file. I have no other ideas. When I created a new Gdoc, copied and pasted the same exact text into it, the code worked without any tweaking. I really appreciate your time and effort on this. I am glad the code was correct. This is a huge improvement for my workflow!